# Why is a definite integral used in solving this differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

The following equation is given in my notes $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \quad\textrm{on domain} \; |x| < \infty, \, t>0$$
The author starts by doing the substitution $$u(x,t) = f(\eta) \\ \eta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{Dt}}$$

I'll skip to the part of the solution where he gets that $$e^{\eta^2/4}\frac{df}{d\eta} = C_0$$
with $C_0$ being some constant. Then he writes $$f(\eta) = \int^\eta_0 e^{-\bar{\eta}^2/4}\,d\bar{\eta} + C_2$$ My question is why does he use a definite integral with limits $0$ and $\eta$ for this last step? My intuition tells me that it is because of the initial conditions imposed on $x$ and $t$ but I don't see how it connects.

Comment: What would you expect instead?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Perhaps an indefinite integral.

Comment: Well the problem there is that we want to specify $f$ as a particular function, whereas the indefinite integral is by definition a family of functions.  In other words, if we want to write the answer as [something] $+C$, it makes no sense for that something *indefinite* integral.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I understand what you are saying so far. Why does the author pick the limits to be $0$ and $\eta$ though?

Comment: Because those are the "simplest choices" that work.  Of course, the top limit needs to be $\eta$, if we want the bottom to be a constant.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Does the decision of $0$ and $\eta$ being the "simplest choices" follow from some principle, or is it just an educated guess?

Comment: The fact that they *do* work follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus.  We did not "solve" for $0$ and $\eta$ in any way, so in that sense I suppose you could call it an "educated guess".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you also add $C_2$ this is equivalent to an indefinite integral, namely

$$
\int_0^\eta e^{-\bar{\eta}^2/4} d\bar{\eta} = \int e^{-\eta^2/4} d\eta + C_3,
$$

where $C_3$ is a fixed constant, but if you add an arbitrary constant, $C_2$, to both sides $C_3 + C_2$ will just become another arbitrary constant.